# Find $b_{n},\ldots ,b_0$ if $a_n \prod^{n-1}_{i=0}(r-i)+a_{n-1}\prod^{n-2}_{i=0}(r-i)+\cdots +a_nr+a_0=\sum\limits_{i=0}^nb_{i}r^i$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial $$\begin{align*}
P(r)=& a_nr(r-1)\cdots (r-(n-1))+a_{n-1}r(r-1)\cdots (r-(n-2))+\cdots +a_1r+a_0\\ =&a_n \prod^{n-1}_{i=0}(r-i)+a_{n-1}\prod^{n-2}_{i=0}(r-i)+\cdots +a_nr+a_0  &&(1)
\end{align*}$$ Let this polynomial be $$\begin{align*}
P&= b_nr^n+b_{n-1}r^{n-1}+\cdots +b_1r+b_0 &&(2)
\end{align*}$$How should I find the coeficient of $(2)$? That is, how should I express thoese $b_{n},b_{n-1},\ldots ,b_1,b_0$ in$(2)$ ?

I tried to directly expand several terms of $(1)$ and hoped to find some patterns, so I can use induction. However, it's quite hard to find a pattern here.

I also tried to find the pattern of expanding $r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots (r-(n-1))$, but this seems not that helpful in dealing with this...
Any help on this? Thanks.

---

Edit:

By a hint in the comment, I regard $a_0,\cdots,a_n$ as the basis of a vector space, and $b_1,\cdots,b_n$ as the basis of another one. By evaluating $r=n-1,n-2,\ldots$ I get :$$\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 & 0&  \cdots &0 \\ 1 &1 &0 &0 & \cdots &0 \\ 1 & 2 &2! &0 &\cdots  & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 3 \cdot2  & 3! & \cdots  & 0 \\ \vdots  &&&&& \vdots  \\ 1 & n & n(n-1) & \cdots  &\cdots & n!   \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_0  \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\  \\ \\ a_n  \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 & 0&  \cdots &0 \\ 1 &1 &1 &1 & \cdots &1 \\ 1 & 2 &2^2 &2 &\cdots  & 2^n \\ 1 & 3 & 3^2   & 3^3 & \cdots  & 3^n \\ \vdots  &&&&& \vdots  \\ 1 & n & n^2 & \cdots  &\cdots & n^n   \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} b_0  \\ b_1 \\ \vdots \\  \\ \\ b_n  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Then I denote the LHS $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and if RHS $n \times n$ matrix $B$, If $B$ is invertible and if I can find the inverse of it, I can use $(B^{-1}A) \vec{a}=\vec{b}$, so for $b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ I can know how to express them in $a$. This seems promising, but how should I know that $B$ is invertible？ Also. if indeed $B$ is invertible, how should I compute $B^{-1}A$? The computation seemingly involves the pretty amount of work...

Comment: Try evaluating $r$ at $n-1,n-2,\ldots,0$.

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, and by your hind, I indeed have some results. May you check this?

Comment: It looks good, but I will not check the computation. You could now try small values of $n$, like $3$ and $4$ (maybe with the aid of the computer) to invert those matrices and perhaps find a pattern. You can also try to prove inductively that you can recover $b_n$ from the previous $a$ and $b$s. Good luck!

Comment: Re why $B$ is invertible, check out Vandermonde matrix/determinant. A form for the inverse is known, though it isn't "pretty".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

Comment: It looks like $B^{-1} A$ has characteristic polynomial $(1-\lambda)^n$. Maybe there's a nice set of generalized eigenvectors for it...